# Contiguous Group By

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

I have the following table:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
ORDER BY id;

id  name    code   time
1    A      111     1
2    A      111     2
3    A      888     3
4    A      888     4
5    A      888     5
6    A      888     6
7    A      888     7
8    A      111     8
9    A      111     9
10    A     111     10
```

I need to get a result like this:

```
name    code    times_between
A       111     1,2
A       888     3,7
A       111     8,10
```

Is it possible to group by "chunks"?
I need to make a distinction based on time, so I can't just group by name,code and get the first and last element only.

Comment: "the order of the table" --- there is no such thing. The data in the table is stored unordered and is not guaranteed to be the same unless you use `ORDER BY` in your queries explicitly.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20130204103454.0b3c6b23@tucholsky.experteer.muc And a lot of other relevant stuff when you google with "postgresql group consecutive" request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is this:

```
with the_table(id, name ,   code  ,  time) as(
select 1, 'A',111   ,  1 union all
select 2, 'A',111   ,  2 union all
select 3, 'A',888  ,   3 union all
select 4, 'A',888  ,   4 union all
select 5, 'A',888 ,    5 union all
select 6, 'A',888   ,  6 union all
select 7, 'A',888  ,   7 union all
select 8, 'A',111  ,   8 union all
select 9, 'A',111   ,  9 union all
select 10, 'A',111  ,   10
)


select name, code, min(time) ||','|| max(time)  from (
    select name, code, time, id,
    row_number() over(order  by id)   -
    row_number() over(partition by name , code order  by id) as grp
    from the_table
) t
group by name, code, grp
order by min(id)
```

(I forgot and just can't find/remember the name of technique, which creates groups `grp`)

Comment: You should use `OVER (ORDER BY time)`, if I interpret the question correctly.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - if I correctly understand, order of "gaps and islands" depends on `id` column